# (Angular2) data is not updating before calling it

Tags: angular

I'm having some problems with getting data from my database. I want to execute a method to get the data every time the user press a button, but something is not working properly.

My code:

```
constructor (private cynomysService: CynomysService, private route:  ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router ){
        ...
//THESE ARE THE SERVICES I'M EXECUTING WHEN MY COMPONENT IS LOADED.
        this.getFavPubli().subscribe((s) => {this.colorearFav()});
        this.getDestPubli().subscribe((s) => {this.colorearDest()});

    }
```

I'll give the example just with one of those methods, just because both of them have the same code.

```
getFavPubli() {
        return this.cynomysService.getFavoritoPublicacion(localStorage.getItem('usuario')).map((fp) => {this.favoritoPublicacion = fp});
    }

addFavorite() {
        this.favoritos = this.publicacionRecibida[0].favoritos;
        this.idRecibido = this.publicacionRecibida[0].idPublicaciones;

        let comprobarFavorito = this.favoritoPublicacion.filter(favorito => {
            return favorito.publicacion == this.route.snapshot.params['id']});

        if(comprobarFavorito.length) {
            let variable = comprobarFavorito[0];
            if(variable.deleted == 0) {
                this.cynomysService.deleteFavPubli(variable.id_favorito_publicacion).subscribe((f) => {this.getFavPubli().subscribe()});
            } else if(variable.deleted == 1) {
                this.cynomysService.deleteFavPubli(variable.id_favorito_publicacion).subscribe((f) => {this.getFavPubli().subscribe()});
            }
        } else if(!comprobarFavorito.length) {
            let newFavUser = {
                publicacion: this.idRecibido,
                usuario: localStorage.getItem('usuario'),
                deleted: 0
            };

            var json = JSON.stringify(newFavUser);
            this.cynomysService.addFavoriteUser(json).subscribe((f) => {this.getFavPubli()});
        }
    }
```

Tecnically I'm executing the method that calls the service everywhere in the function: If I insert a new favorite, I launch the method. If I update the favorite to deleted, I launch the method. If I update the favorite to not deleted, I execute the service as well... But still doing that, the first time I load the component (when the table in database is empty) and I press favorite button it inserts the favorite with every click...

Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: try putting the call in ngOnInit() method inside the component . also implement ngInit

Comment: I moved it to ngOnInit and nothing changed

Comment: can you log and check if that method is exceuted on when the component is loaded , please update the question too once

Comment: I actually checked it. What that method should do is to add a new fav or modify it, and It actually does (I checked it with the db), then when the favorite is added another method checks if "deleted" column is false or true and fills the favorite icon with some color (like twitter) if deleted == 0. So, yes, when I refresh this component (or I go to another one and I return to this one) it executes the method.